min_date and max_date are ignored when searching?
I'm trying to search for a specific time period using the WTelegramClient library, but these parameters are ignored returning the result for all time
var search = await TgClient.Messages_Search(id, string.Empty, null, new DateTime(2023, 08, 31), new DateTime(2024,08,01,23,59,59));

Messages sent between 08/31/2023 and 08/01/2024 were expected, but the search result returned does not take the period
